# Google Maps API v3 click event not working in Ionic emulator or device

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have a google maps implementation with various dropped pins. When clicked they open a information Window with a simple string. This all works well and dandy in the Ionic serve. But does not do anything in the iOS emulator or running in the device. When running on the simulator or device I get no error or see any message associated with the event. Reading up on this issue I did set `data-tap-disable="true"` on the div we're the map resides. Can't seem to find any other solution. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you, try putting `data-tap-disabled="true"` on the div that contains the map.  I had to take it even a step further and write something to apply `data-tap-disabled="true"` only when the info-window is showing.

Note I used `data-tap-disabled` while you're saying you tried `data-tap-disable`.

Answer (score 0):

// Fix for Google AutoComplete Places Javascript API on iOS
WORK and tested on iphone5/6/7

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g)) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            let container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container')[0];
            // Fix for Google AutoComplete Places Javascript API on iOS
            if (container) {
                container.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: The above fix worked for me on my ionic angular app but only the first time I load the view, the second time I return to the view the event is no longer fired :(

Found that the root cause was the **'pac-container'** div is created each time I return to the view, so the fix is simply remove it before init the autocomplete

 `let container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container')[0];
 if(container) container.remove();`